# Has Syria protested the violation of its airspace by US and European military aircraft?

Tags: syria, united-nations, sovereignty, international-relations

Often when one country violates the sovereignty of another, by military jet flyover, for example, the country protests at the United Nations since the Charter of the United Nations forbids its members from attacking or infringing on the territory belonging to other members.

Nevertheless, I cannot find any record of Syria protesting the violation of its airspace by US and European military aircraft at the UN or any similar venue. Have they done so?

Comment: US and European countries seem to ignore international laws when it doesn't suit them.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they have done it, I found this recent article, for example:

"Damascus condemned Turkish incursion into the Syrian territory after Turkey’s tanks and Special Forces supported by the **Turkish and US aircraft** and Syrian rebels launched an offensive on the Syrian northern border town of Jarablus, calling it “a national security issue.”"

"[...] a Syrian government official told SANA and once again called on the UN to “put an end to this aggression” and to make Turkey and the US-led coalition fulfill the UN resolutions related to closing the borders and preventing the terrorists from receiving funding and support from abroad.

The Syrian UN envoy also said Wednesday that the Syrian government did not request any such aid from Turkey and stressed that all foreign forces fighting terrorism in Syria should coordinate their actions with the Syrian Army."

https://www.rt.com/news/357060-syria-condemn-turkey-operation/